# "beginning" is to "prefix" as "end" is to "suffix" as "middle" is to... what?

Tags: suffixes, prefixes, affixes

The word "prefix" describes something affixed to the beginning of a word and the word "suffix" describes something affixed to the end of a word.  What is the analog of these for something affixed to or making up the middle of a word?

Comment: ... as "middle" is to "infix", as used in a **Riley riddle**.

Comment: Thanks for that! Never heard of a Riley Riddle before.  Learned two new things today!  For others that have also not heard of a Riley Riddle, here is the first one I came across:

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93230/short-riley-riddle

Comment: The three parts may overlap in a Riley riddle, as do the prefix and infix in your link.

Comment: Like uneffingbelievable?

Comment: ...as "beginning and end" are to "circumfix." And the opposite of all of these is a "disfix," something removed from a word to change the meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word is "infix". SOED: 2. *Gram.* an affix inserted into a word.